# Range of RF module (and antennae) given then "sensitivity" in dBm?

Tags: rf, design

Is there some simple (maybe somewhat rough, i.e. not very accurate) way to determine the farthest distance that an RF module pair (i.e. an RX-TX, or pair of TRX's) can communicate reliably, given the "sensitivity" (in dBm) ratings of the modules ?

Also, can someone explain the difference & significance of --

- sensitivity of the module itself
- sensitivity of the antenna
  and how the RX + TX RF properties interact.

***Edited:***
Here are the Sparkful RX/TX module pair which we could use as reference.

[transmitter](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10535) and [receiver](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10533)

While I might end up using different modules, I wanted to know how to figure out the distance for which they work, in clear-line-of-sight.

Manufacturers or vendors (especially hobby electronics vendors) sometimes do provide the information on max. distance, but I've rarely found it to be true. Even in clear-line-of-sight.

Also, is there some rough yard-stick by which one could estimate the drop in effective communication distance, with introduction of obstructions, s.a. concrete walls ? Something like, for every concrete wall, reduce the power by 50% !

Comment: Need some additional information.  What modules are you using? What kind of antennas at each end of the link? Antennas are not rated using sensitivity but in gain as dBi or dBd - gain compared to an isotropic antenna or a dipole antenna respectively.  What kind of feedline and the length? Last question, what modulation will you be using?

Comment: Updated question. The antenna I am using are the quarter-length (23cm in case of 315MHz module) of copper wire. Nothing fancy, but I have seen GSM "Stub" antenna for instance, having that dBi rating (sorry, confused it with dBm). Not sure what you mean by feedline. The modulation in question is ASK/OOK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, dBm is a unit of power. 0dBm = 1mW, 20dBm = 100mW, -20dBm = 0.01mW.

Sensitivity of a receiver is the minimal power of the signal that the receiver still can receive (with the specified error rate). Antenna gain is how much power the antenna can collect, or rather, how much it is better than an ideal isotropic (radiating/accepting in all directions equally) antenna. The units are dBi. Isotropic antenna is 0dBi. Any antenna that has gain above 0dBi usually receives from some directions better than others (for example, there usually is no point receiving from straight up or down). Antenna gain s applicable for both, the transmitter and the receiver.

You also need to know the power of the transmitter (convert it to dBm if it is in mW) and the frequency.

The power received is calculated like this

`Pr = Pt + Gt - L + Gr`

Where Pt is the transmitter power (dBm), Gt and Gr is the gain of transmitter and receiver antennas, Pr is the received power and L is loss.

If Pr is higher than the receiver sensitivity then your link will work.

Loss is calculated like this:

`L = Lfs + Lc + Lo`

Lc is the signal loss in cables, connectors etc.
Lfs is the free space loss and Lo are other losses.

`Lfs = 32.4 + 20 log(f) + 20 log(d)`

Where "log" is the base 10 logarithm, f is frequency in MHz and d is distance in km.

Calculating signal loss is very complex, however, if you assume that the antennas are high above ground and in line of sight of each other, calculating free space loss is enough. In a city or indoors you also need to calculate Lo - this can get very complicated. There are various signal propagation models suitable for different areas and there also is software that can help you calculate it. Those models usually calculate Lo - what you need to add to the free space path loss to compensate for the fact that the signal is not going trough free space.

Another important thing is that the receiver sensitivity is an ideal measure, that is, it only applies if there is no noise. if there is noise, then your signal will have to be stronger.

Comment: Another important factor is the existence of signals in the environment from other sources.  If you're trying to transmit data at 2.456GHz and someone else is sending data at the same frequency with the same modulation scheme, even the most wonderfully-engineered receiver is going to be unable to reliably receive your data unless it receives it more strongly as the other guy's.

Comment: @supercat, happened to us one time, we were in the 900MHz band, we had been to many places, the test facility we used was directly underneath a cell tower in that band. Talk about having no chance to communicate over that.

Comment: Thanks Pentium100 for answering and @stevenh for editing. Is there any well-accepted (not looking for the mathematical model), thumb-rule, that determines the "loss" due to concrete walls ? A while back, while reading an article on GSM radiation-exposure, I saw some figures which said that every "standard concrete wall" causes signal-strength to drop to x0.1 of signal-strength outside. Can this taken to be roughly true for 315/433MHz ISM band comm., given ASK/OOK modulation ?

Answer (score 1):

Feedline is what is used between the transmitter/receiver and the antenna. There's loss associated with feedlines that need to be taken into consideration when determining the overall performance of the radio link. Reading the specs on both devices,  500 feet is the max the pair can operate. There are several issues that will greatly impact performance.  The receiver has a very wide bandpass compared to the bandwidth of the signal. This means the receiver will have a lot of received noise which will greatly increase the bit error rate. The other issue is the amplitude-shift keying or ASK. ASK is linear and sensitive to atmospheric noise, distortions, propagation conditions and other radio frequency interference.  These will also impact performance.  To get an idea on overall system performance, take the output power of the transmitter, subtract the losses from the feedline from both ends, add any antenna gain on both ends.   You can use the freespace equation above to figure out the received signal strength, when all that's done, you'll have a fair idea if it'll work. This doesn't take into consideration other nearby sources of RF near the same frequency of these modules.

One way to improve the performance is to use a slow data rate. Faster data rates are prone to noise that could wipe out an entire bit or two. If you don't have a lot of data to transmit, slow data rates will spend a longer time at amplitude so a brief noise burst won't mask an entire bit.

I would also consider sweeping the frequency range of these devices with a scanner to determine if any other RF sources are present that could impact performance.

Comment: Thanks for answering @MarkSchoonover, and explaining very lucidly. My application can live with pretty low data-rate. Maybe something in the order of few hundred bits-per-second, so I guess this may not be a terrible bet.